# How can I upload the image file by using formdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem on my code. I want to upload the image file by using formdata and ajax to the server side python program. But I got django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'image'" error in my server uwsgi.log. I think it may not upload the image file to the server, but I don't understand what is wrong on my code.

My client code is the following.

```
function imageFileUploader(imageType, image) {

    var credentials = {
        filetype: imageType,
    };
    var image_file = image;

    $.ajax({
        url: HOST_NAME + "user/api/get_filename/",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: credentials,
        timeout: 10000,
    })

    .done(function (data) {

        jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        image_file_name = jsondata.fileurl;

        // Test if the image is shown -> success
        document.getElementById("previewimage").src = image

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('filename', image_file_name);
        formData.append('image', image);

        $.ajax({
            url: HOST_NAME + "user/api/file_uploader/",
            type: 'POST',
                timeout: 10000,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
            alert("File upload completed...");
        })
        .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        })
    .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    })

}

function snapPicture () {

    navigator.camera.getPicture (onSuccess, onFail,
        {quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true});

    function onSuccess (imageURI) {

        var file_name = imageFileUploader("T", imageURI);
        if (file_name == "") {
            console.log("False");
        }
        else {
            image_send(file_name);
        }
    }

    function onFail (message) {
        console.log("False");
    }
}
```

And my server side code is the following.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    outputLogFile("Upload Function is called...")
    req_file_name = request.data['filename']
    req_image = request.FILES['image']
```

I can get filename from the client when I comment the code of image. Please give me an advice.

Comment: post your html form

Comment: Also show us where the `image` and `image_file_name` variables are coming from.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I don't use form to get the image file. I am making smartphone app and image file was from camera or album.

Comment: I add the code which get the image from camera. Please give me an advice.

Comment: I think `image` does not in `request.FILES`, which holds data uploaded by `file input`